# VS2017 crashing after Delete File on TFS

Tags: tfs, crash, visual-studio-2017, source-control-explorer

When I go to Source Control Explorer and try to Delete Files, Visual Studio 2017 crashes.

Does anybody know solutions for the issue?

Comment: Are you using GIT or TFVS?  Did you try and repair visual studio?

Comment: The only thing I tried before was cleaning the  local user TFS cache and did not solve the issue,

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact version of VS 2017 do you use? Seems there is an issue on earlier version of VS 2017. See the issue here : https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21301

Just try below items and check if that works for you:

- Upgrade to the latest version of VS 2017.
- Try deleting the contents of the **.vs** folder in your solution
  directory.
- Remap the workspace or create a new workspace to check that again.
- Start VS with another user :

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
  runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`
- Reset user data:

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
  devenv.exe /resetuserdata`